# Solidity Error: Struct containing a (nested) mapping cannot be constructed

Tags: compilation, ethereum, solidity

My version of solc:

```
    "solc": "^0.7.1",
```

When I try to construct a struct that contains mapping, I got this error:
"Struct containing a (nested) mapping cannot be constructed"

This is my solidity code.

Campaign.sol

```
contract Campaign {
struct Request {
    ...
// I guess this might cause an error
    mapping(address => bool) approvals;

}

constructor(uint256 minimum, address creator) {
    ...
}

function createRequest(
    string memory description,
    uint256 value,
    address payable recipient
) public onlyManager {
    Request memory newRequest = Request({ 
        // Here the compiler complains 
    });
}
...
```

If I want to put a mapping inside of my Request struct, is there any other way around?
Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think I find an answer [here](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/070-breaking-changes.html?highlight=struct#mappings-outside-storage)

I put the mapping outside of the `struct`, and the error is gone:

```
contract Campaign {
    struct Request {
        //...
    }
    mapping(address => bool) approvals;
```

I'm not sure it solves the problem totally. I'll update if there is another issue.

Answer (score 6):

from 0.7.0 do like below:

```
    struct Request{
            string description;
            uint value;
            address recipient;
            bool complete;
            uint approvalsCount;
            mapping(address => bool) approvals;
        }
        
    uint numRequests;
    mapping (uint => Request) requests;
    
    function createRequest (string memory description, uint value,
            address recipient) public{
                Request storage r = requests[numRequests++];
                r.description = description;
                r.value = value;
                r.recipient = recipient;
                r.complete = false;
                r.approvalsCount = 0;
            
        }
```